# Sliding window interpolation

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I need to resample graph based on a series of points (with variable step) and it's bounds. E.g on the picture X coordinates on the graph are [0, 3, 7, 10, 12, 15] (indicated by the blue vertical lines). Graph has an upper-bound and lower-bound (indicated by red lines). I need to resample this graph with fixed step, for example with step=2.

[image: Plot]

I know that it is possible to interpolate this graph and then sample it with fixed step. But the graph is huge. I need some quick and simple algorithm that works with sliding window.

Comment: I don't know what your definition of sliding window interpolation is, but perhaps piecewise curve fitting is acceptable. You basically look at three consecutive points at a time, and fit a 3 degree polynomial to those points, taking the final slope of the last piece into account. Forms a good looking curve, and it's "local" in the sense that it processes just a few points at a time. You might even manage to work it out so that it respects those bounds.

Comment: Looks like that's what I need. Can you answer this question for me to accept it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to look up the details. I just remember that this was a useful approach from my numerics course. Feel free to formulate an answer based on my comment.